# Mysql Update Query cast varchar to string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a column `meta_key` which is `varchar.` Now the values when `meta_key='_price'` are numbers like 10,20 etc. I want to increase this column by percentage.

Here is what I am using:

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_key=meta_key+meta_key*($percent/100) where meta_key='_price'
```

But as metakey is not number therefore I have a problem. How to convert varchar to int and then update?

Ahmar

Comment: `meta_key` column contains `_price`, as mentioned in your `WHERE` condition. How do you want to convert it to `int` ? I mean, what is the purpose ? It is going to be `0` anyway, no?

Comment: if you are writing inside php , get value of column and store in php variable and use that php varaibale for calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this Manual Page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

`CAST(meta_key AS UNSIGNED)` should work for you.